# How to apply a command to each line in pipe?

Tags: bash

I want to apply a command to each line of piped stdin like so:

```
cat file.txt | grep ... | ./filter | wc -l
```

the problem is `./filter` accepts only a single line of input and gives a single line of output. I've tried `xargs` but it spawns a subshell and I can't capture it's output to continue working with the result. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: `accepts only a single line of input` As an argument or on standard input? `I've tried xargs but it spawns a subshell` xargs does not spawn a subshell, did you specify xargs to spawn it? Also xargs passes the line as an argument, not input. `I can't capture it's output` why you "can't"? `Is there an easy way to do that?` Do you know how to read a file or stream line by line? https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: `./filter` accepts stdin and outputs to stdout. You are right about xargs passing lines as arguments and this is why a subshell is spawned - to convert it to stdin `xargs -n1 sh -c "echo \$0 | ./filter"`

Comment: Great that code is almost fine, except `$0` undergoes word splitting and filename expansion. I would do `xargs -d '\n' -n1 bash -c './filter <<<$0'`, with `<<<` I wouldn't need a pipe. So `I can't capture it's output` Why you "can't"?

Comment: Oh wait it works, I had a mistake in other place and thought the output was being lost.

Comment: I guess I should delete the question now?

Answer (score 0):

If it accepts a single line, then you should put it in a loop if you want to process multiple lines,

```
cat file.txt | 
  grep ...   | 
  while read line ; do
      echo "$line" | ./filter
  done       | 
  wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a command for each line you can read a line into a variable and use the variable as a standard input. (Also, let’s avoid [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).)

```bash
grep ... < file.txt |
while IFS= read -r line; do
  ./filter <<< "$line"
done |
wc -l
```

In this case it looks like things may get *way* easier if you instead write the whole `filter` in `awk`. Because it will give you `wc -l` for free (`NR`), plus line and record splitting and filtering better than what `grep` can do.